# Symfony CMF: Unrecognized option "use_sonata_admin" under "cmf_routing.dynamic.persistence.phpcr"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-cmf

I try to install **Symfony CMF** with `SonataDoctrinePHPCRAdminBundle()` and `CmfTreeBrowserBundle()`.

According to docs there's an option in `app/config.yml` to prevent administrative routes be view-able in admin interface:

```
# app/config/config.yml
cmf_routing:
    # ...
    dynamic:
        # ...
        persistence:
            phpcr:
                # ...
                use_sonata_admin: false
```

But I receive an error both in  the console and on the site:

```
"Unrecognized option "use_sonata_admin" under 
"cmf_routing.dynamic.persistence.phpcr"
```

What could it be?

Comment: Could you link to the docs where you read about this setting?

Comment: Yes, sure. http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/tutorial/sonata-admin.html

Comment: we are in the process of moving to cmf version 2. the tutorial is currently outdated. sonata admin is now all configured at the new admin bundle, not on cmf_routing anymore. if you want something that works as documented, please use the 1.3 release and the 1.3 documentation. if you are trying out new things, see https://github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf-docs/milestone/4 for what documentation can be expect to work or not yet. any help in updating the doc is appreciated of course ;-)

Comment: @dbu That sounds like great information. Could you post it as an answer, so it's easier for others to find (comments are kind of "second-class citizens" around here, and liable to be overlooked or even deleted).

Answer (score 0):

we are in the process of moving to cmf version 2. the tutorial is currently outdated. sonata admin is now all configured at the new admin bundle, not on cmf_routing anymore. if you want something that works as documented, please use the 1.3 release and the 1.3 documentation. if you are trying out new things, see github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf-docs/milestone/4 for what documentation can be expect to work or not yet. any help in updating the doc is appreciated of course ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! Version 1.3 worked for me. 
I'd like to help with the docs, but my English leaves much to be desired :)